# Can I modify below GroupBy clause into better one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider following cases

```
CASE 1:  tbl_a
---------------
| colA | colB |
---------------      expected O/P:   1  0 
|  1   |  0   |
---------------

CASE 2:  tbl_a
---------------
| colA | colB |
---------------      expected O/P:   1  1
|  1   |  1   |
---------------

CASE 3:  tbl_a
---------------
| colA | colB |
---------------     expected O/P:   1  1
|  1   |  0   |
|  1   |  1   |
---------------

CASE 4:  tbl_a
---------------
| colA | colB |
---------------     expected O/P:  NULL NULL
| null | null |
---------------
```

The query is simple, If there is a record where colA = 1 and colB = 1 then return it, if no such record exists then return the existing record for colA = 1.
I have tried various ways. I came with groupBy clause but is there a simple way to do it.

If I use ColA = 1 And colB = 1 then it fails for case 1 it returns no rows.

```
 SELECT colA, Max(colb) group by (colA)
```

Is this the valid query? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For `MAX`, `NULL` is eliminated from aggregate. See this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.  It provides the desired results for the posted cases.

```
SELECT TOP 1 colA, colB 
  FROM tbl_a 
 WHERE colA = 1 OR colA IS NULL
 ORDER BY colA DESC, colB DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query that you wrote fits the data to well, but doesn't work for the general case which you described.

Try the below script and play with the value for the `@scenario` variable to see what data it returns for different data.

Use / adapt the last query for your table structure.

```
declare @tbl table (colA int, colB int)
declare @scenario char(1) = 'D'

if @scenario = 'A'
    insert @tbl values (1, 0)
else if @scenario = 'B'
    insert @tbl values (1, 1)
else if @scenario = 'C'
    insert @tbl values (1, 0), (1, 1)
else if @scenario = 'D'
    insert @tbl values (null, null)

select *
    from @tbl
    where (colA = 1 and colB = 1)
        or (colA = 1 and not exists (select 1 from @tbl where colA = 1 and colB = 1))
        or (colA is null and colB is null and not exists (select 1 from @tbl where colA = 1 and colB = 1))
```

You can also test the query with "more random data" in each scenario, like below:

```
declare @tbl table (colA int, colB int)
declare @scenario char(1) = 'B'

if @scenario = 'A'
    insert @tbl values (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, null)
else if @scenario = 'B'
    insert @tbl values (1, 1), (1, 0), (null, null)
else if @scenario = 'C'
    insert @tbl values (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (null, 0)
else if @scenario = 'D'
    insert @tbl values (null, null)

select *
    from @tbl
    where (colA = 1 and colB = 1)
        or (colA = 1 and not exists (select 1 from @tbl where colA = 1 and colB = 1))
        or (colA is null and colB is null and not exists (select 1 from @tbl where colA = 1 and colB = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using `row_number` with ordering based on your priority and getting the row with the minimum row number as the result.

```
select colA,colB
from (select x.*,min(rn) over() as minrn 
      from (select t.*
            ,row_number() over(order by case when colA=1 and colB=1 then 1
                                             when colA=1 then 2
                                        else 3 end) as rn
             from t 
            ) x
     ) y 
where rn=minrn
```